# Toggle isActive className on div element inside map function

Tags: javascript, css, algorithm, reactjs

So I'm having a bunch of items generated inside of map function

```
{Items.map((item, i) => (
        <div className='nav col-4' key={i}>
          <div className={be('Items', 'item', props.isActive ? 'isActive' : '')} onClick={props.handleActive} key={title}>
            <span>{I18n.translate(`item.${title}`)}</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
```

the props.isActive class should highlight only the one item that is clicked on. Now it highlights all of them. I know how to this outside ofmap function but here I'm kinda strugling.

`handleActive` is only toggling isActive piece of state

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   handleClick = (id) => {
    this.props.handleActive(id)

   }    



{Items.map((item, i) => (
            <div className='nav col-4' key={i}>
              <div className={be('Items', 'item', props.isActive ? 'isActive' : '')} onClick={()=>this.handleClick(i)} key={title}>
                <span>{I18n.translate(`item.${title}`)}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
```

In parent component `handleActive` will be called with the id.There u can set the **isActive** prop.

And in the child component, the item will be set to active or inactive

Comment: Came up with similar solution. defined `id={i}` on item div and then passed `event.currentTarget.id` from the parent component. Then i just check if clicked items id is equal to what is passed e.g. `i === props.index ? 'isActive' : ''`

Answer (score 1):

You are testing the same props.isActive over all your items. you need to keep an internal state and keep state of which item has been clicked.

```
props.isActive ? 'isActive' : ''
```